# Can I keep /home and /opt when reinstalling 64-bit over 32-bit?

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, 64-bit, system-installation

I tried upgrading Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 (32-bit), but the upgrade failed, and the PC is not booting, so now I am planning to go for fresh install of 14.04 64-bit.

I had sevaral data partitions (`/opt`, `/home`) which are 32-bit (from earlier). Can I install the 64 bit version without getting these partitions modified? I know that I must not format these, or should I install 14.04 32-bit if there is risk for data loss in those partitions?

Comment: @girardengo Thank you for working on disambiguating the [tag:installation] tag, but please don't *just* change the tag, also perform other necessary edits such as formatting, spelling, etc.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for the advice. I will try to be more careful, but English is not my language, for me it is not so easy.

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit OS is capable of using 32-bit partitions without problems.